# What is the convention for Lisp filename extension?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, filenames, pathname

".el" is the convention for filename ending with Emacs Lisp programs. What is the convention when writing Common Lisp programs, please?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) and the [Google Common Lisp Style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lispguide.xml?showone=Comment_semicolons#Comment_semicolons) both suggest `.lisp`.

[*Practical Common Lisp* suggests `.lisp` or `.cl`.](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lather-rinse-repeat-a-tour-of-the-repl.html#saving-your-work)

Note, I'm not a Common Lisp programmer by any measure, so I have no idea if `.lisp` is actually used in practice.

Comment: I just checked my Quicklisp installation that has a lot of the packages downloaded. There are a few `.cl` files (mostly related to closer-mop). The rest are `.lisp`

Answer (score 39):

Common Lisp pathname types for source code:

- **`lisp` is the default. Use this if possible.**
- `lsp` if the pathname type allows only three characters
- `l` if the pathname type should be one character (rare).

The pathname type `cl` is mostly not used. You can see it sometimes in older code bases or projects which use several different Lisp dialects.

For compiled code the pathname type can be computed in Common Lisp using the function `COMPILE-FILE-PATHNAME` (here 64bit LispWorks on a Mac):

```
CL-USER > (pathname-type (compile-file-pathname "foo.lisp"))
"64xfasl"
```